# Which of these is the most efficient?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, fastcgi, lighttpd, wsgi

### Question

Which of these is the quickest?

I'm using lighttpd's `mod_fastcgi`, Python 2.7 and `flup.server.fcgi.WSGIServer`.

Should I **yield strings directly in `some_output_function`, then return from `app`**?

```
def app(env, start):
    start('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return some_output_function()

def some_output_function():
    yield function_that_returns_a_string()
    yield 'yada yada'
    yield another_function_that_returns_a_string()

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

Should I **return an array from `some_output_function`, then return from `app`**?

```
def app(env, start):
    start('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return some_output_function()

def some_output_function():
    out = []
    out.append(function_that_returns_a_string())
    out.append('yada yada')
    out.append(another_function_that_returns_a_string())
    return out

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

Should I **yield a last-minute joined array from `some_output_function`, then return from `app`**?

```
def app(env, start):
    start('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return some_output_function()

def some_output_function():
    out = []
    out.append(function_that_returns_a_string())
    out.append('yada yada')
    out.append(another_function_that_returns_a_string())
    yield ''.join(out)

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

Should I **return a last-minute joined array from `some_output_function`, then yield from `app`**?

```
def app(env, start):
    start('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield some_output_function()

def some_output_function():
    out = []
    out.append(function_that_returns_a_string())
    out.append('yada yada')
    out.append(another_function_that_returns_a_string())
    return ''.join(out)

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

### Test results

By creating a simple test application, with the output function having one function call, then sixteen 'yada yada' strings, then another function call as the output, I gathered some surprising average request times, using ApacheBench.

```
sudo ab -n10000 -c128 localhost/testapp/
```

- **44 ms** to yield strings directly in `some_output_function`, then return from `app`
- **44 ms** to return an array from `some_output_function`, then return from `app`
- **30 ms** to yield a last-minute joined array from `some_output_function`, then return from `app`
- **30 ms** to return a last-minute joined array from `some_output_function`, then yield from `app`

Even more interesting, is that when increasing the number of 'yada yada' output strings eight-fold, to 128 'yada yada' output strings, these are the results:

- **146 ms** to yield strings directly in `some_output_function`, then return from `app`
- **146 ms** to return an array from `some_output_function`, then return from `app`
- **30 ms** to yield a last-minute joined array from `some_output_function`, then return from `app`
- **30 ms** to return a last-minute joined array from `some_output_function`, then yield from `app`

It appears that a common factor to save time is building a string array, then joining it just before exiting the inner output function, instead of yielding everywhere. Whether you yield inside and return outside, or return inside and yield inside, doesn't appear to change anything.

So the only question now, really, is, should I yield inside or outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule generators are more efficient than lists when dealing with a lot of data. A list will be less overhead if the number of elements is small (e.g. in your example, only three elements).

Whichever method you choose, it will most likely be dwarfed by the time spent fetching data from the cache or the datastore (dozens to hundreds of milliseconds). Shaving 10ms of response time is probably not worth worrying about.

The reason why generators should be used is not for speed, but because large responses will be streamed to the client, which will use less memory and free up the server to process more requests. This is especially beneficial when done with an async server (e.g. gunicorn with eventlet workers, Tornado, etc.).

To answer this question:

> So the only question now, really, is, should I yield inside or outside?

Practically it should not make any difference.

Comment: That's a very good point, but my primitive test shows that request time appears to increase together with more `yield` statements, but stays at a flat time (or a far smaller, invisible increase in time) when using a list, joining, then yielding once. Should I really be using generators with yield statements alone? **Edit:** on second thought, would it be reasonable to say that the generator method is lighter on memory, but slower, and the list method is faster, but consumes more memory?

Comment: I think you are seeing an increase in time when using yield because you are yielding lots of small strings. Yielding 1000 small strings will have higher overhead than a list of 1000 elements.

Comment: Try returning a 1MB (or higher) response with a generator that splits the data into chunks that are 128KB (or higher) each vs. a list with the same data. The generator approach allows you to tune the system better (e.g. higher memory usage for a faster response). With a list you only have one option: store everything in memory and send it all in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Producing lots of small strings, versus a single big string is slower because the WSGI specification requires that the underlying WSGI server/adapter perform a flush of each string before writing the next. A flush of a string can go through many layers depending on the server used eventually getting down to a flush on a socket. As you are doing this many times it will be more expensive that writing a single larger string.

Comment: That makes sense. So, each `yield` in my innermost function in the slower methods could possibly make the small string do a full trip all to the 'outside', and the faster methods don't eat more time for more strings because it is not forced to do a flush for each string?